# and therefore structure

Tags: sentence-structure

I came across this sentence and I would like to rewrite it in different ways ?

> This car has a six-litre engine and therefore uses a lot of petrol.([source)](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv269.shtml)

So can I write

1. This car has a six-litre engine and it therefore uses a lot of petrol.
2. This car has a six-litre engine, it therefore uses a lot of petrol.
3. This car has a six-litre engine; therefore uses a lot of petrol.
4. This car has a six-litre engine; therefore,it uses a lot of petrol.

Comment: Number 2 is a comma splice and 99% teachers will mark it as an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence #1 is correct.  I'd put a comma after "engine", but that's just a minor style thing.  It's correct as is.

Sentence #2 is incorrect.  It's a comma splice.  To make it correct, you need to replace the comma with a semicolon.

Sentence #3 is incorrect.  You need a subject for "uses".  To accomplish this, either (1) put the "it" back in (so that "it" is the subject of "uses"), or (2) put the "and" back in (so that "this car" is the subject of "uses").

Sentence #4 is correct.  Very formal, but correct.

Comment: I would not use a semi-colon at all between dependent phrases.

Answer (score 1):

1. This car has a six-litre engine and it therefore uses a lot of petrol.
   **Yes**
2. This car has a six-litre engine, it therefore uses a lot of petrol. **Yes, though it sounds a little too formal.**
3. This car has a six-litre engine; therefore uses a lot of petrol. **No.**
4. This car has a six-litre engine; therefore,it uses a lot of petrol.  **Yes, but the comma seems unnecessary**

Comment: You can also say Number 1 without **it**. I think this is what you are trying to say with Number 3.

Comment: @δοῦλος without it it turns to be original sentence.:) lol

Comment: That's true δοῦλος but you do need the "and".  BTW how do I pronounce "δοῦλος"??

Comment: @bh do you think I should use semi-colon in the second sentence and the third sentence is incomplete ?

Comment: I don't bother reading original sentences. - lol (Actually I was reading quickly and didn't notice it.) @bh, the pronunciation is approximately 'DO- loase  You can hear it at Forvo, except [The pronunciation at forvo](http://www.forvo.com/word/%CE%B4%CE%BF%E1%BF%A6%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82/) stretches out the first syllable a bit much.